# Amazon alexa working

Tags: machine-learning, alexa-skills-kit

A simple search of "how alexa works" yielded no results so here it is.

If you go through the documentation for  [utterances](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/defining-the-voice-interface#h2_sample_utterances) the need to exhaustively list out all possible variations is ridiculous. For example you need to list down the following variations separately to support them.

- what's my horoscope
- what is my horoscope
- what my horoscope is

Maybe I didn't interpret the documentation correctly but I'm just curious as to where exactly the machine learning algorithms come in for identifying intents and skills.

Any pointers to helpful resources will be fine too.

Comment: From my experience building several Alexa skills, utterances provide a more general guidance to Alexa, and not a strict list of what is supported. Alexa is typically able to correctly identify close but not exact matches. I think the biggest value in listing the variations out is that it enables Alexa to more accurately differentiate between similar intents.

Comment: @RonLisle can you provide an example of the close variations? I'm trying to figure out how close of a variation would it identify

Comment: For example, Alexa seems quite capable of determining that "it is" is the same as "its", and can handle "a" vs "an". Where Alexa needs help is when you switch propositional phrases (eg. "there is a dog in the back" vs "in the back, there is a dog"). I suggest experimenting in portal using the test panel. It's quick and easy to add utterances, and see how well Alexa recognizes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pure pattern matching on the transcribed text. We are still in 21st century ...

Comment: Yet alexa is always evolving

Comment: Is there some source you can point me to on this. I would really appreciate that.